# Replacing linebreak with shift-enter in selenium ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, multiline

I've been having a lot of trouble with multiline inputs in Selenium. From what I've learned on google, the \n character essentially enters a new line. That makes it such that I can't send a block multiline input as one paragraph text. I want to be able to replace the \n characters with a shift-enter (simultaneous) keystroke.

I've tried using different methods but none of them seem to work.

The string I'm trying to send is:

```
reply_messages = [
"FREE PILLOW - Thank you for your patience! \n To redeem your FREE pillow, just use the LINK IN OUR BIO and ADD TO CART - just cover shipping, no additional charges!"]
```

I eventually send the string with the line: `reply_input.send_keys(reply_messages)`

When I use selenium to input reply_messages, it outputs each of the lines as separate lines.

Essentially, it will send the first line, enter it into the chat window, then send the second line and enter it into the chat window, instead of entering the first line, adding a linebreak, entering the second line, and sending that entire spaced paragraph as one message.

I want to thus replace the linebreak with a shift-enter keystroke so that the browser doesn't register the newline as its own enter keystroke.

With the linebreak, the string is sent as two separate messages.

Comment: You should mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is an escape character which represents a line break. The keyboard keys you press to get that character don't have anything to do with your problem - Enter and Shift+Enter both add a `\n` to the chat text input box.

What **does** matter is how the chat window is programmed. When deciding if the button that was pressed means the message should be sent, the chat window isn't looking for text characters, it's looking for keyboard keys.

With Selenium you'll need to simulate the keyboard key presses, not the text that is filled into the text box. Check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115754/how-to-enter-shift-ctrl-s-in-selenium). As noted in that answer, you'll want to use something like [`Actions#keyDown`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#keyDown-java.lang.CharSequence-) or [`Actions#keyUp`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#keyUp-java.lang.CharSequence-).